# Select para vencimento de cartão

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5

Queria fazer dois campos select um para o mês e outro para o ano para usar como datas de validade de um cartão, mas queria que fosse gerado dinamicamente e que ao selecionar o ano de 2017 por exemplo aparece somente os meses que faltam para acabar o ano que no caso na data de hoje apareceria somente dezembro. Fiz somente uma estrutura básica em html.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <label>Mês</label>
   <select required ng-model="customer.monthCard">
     <option value="01">Janeiro</option>
     <option value="02">Favereiro </option>
     <option value="03">Março</option>
     <option value="04">Abril</option>
     <option value="05">Maio</option>
     <option value="06">Junho</option>
     <option value="07">Julho</option>
     <option value="08">Agosto</option>
     <option value="09">Setembro</option>
     <option value="10">Outubro</option>
     <option value="11">Novembro</option>
     <option value="12">Dezembro</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <label>Ano</label>
    <select required ng-model="customer.yearCard">
      <option value="18"> 2018</option>
      <option value="19"> 2019</option>
      <option value="20"> 2020</option>
      <option value="21"> 2021</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Por questões de segurança, aconselho a fazer esta verificação através da programação que utiliza na linguagem dinâmica, por ex: PHP. Pois qualquer pessoa com conhecimento no Console do navegador poderá remover esta verificação.

Comment: Minha ideia seria por meio de javaScript e Angular gerar os anos(até 2027 por exemplo) ao carregar a pagina sendo que o ano atual recebe somente os meses que vem apos o mês atual e então carregar dinamicamente na pagina. As validações vão ser feitas todas no servidor, seria algo mais voltado para interface mesmo.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade, a verificação poderia muito bem ser feita no frontend, desde que no backend haja uma verificação do tipo: Se a data informada não for uma data, ou for anterior à data de hoje, retorne erro

Comment: Sim, com certeza. Portanto que no backend também possua. Acho trabalhoso fazer dois tipos de verificação, enquanto uma já seria suficiente. Mas, cada caso é um caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz algo que pode quebrar um galho

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <label>Ano</label>
  <select required ng-model="customer.yearCard">
    <option value="{{ano}}" ng-repeat="ano in AnosCard"> {{ano}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <label>Mês</label>
   <select ng-disabled="!customer.yearCard" required ng-model="customer.monthCard">
     <option value="{{mes}}" ng-repeat="mes in mesesCard">{{mes}}</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
        function geraDatas(){
        var data = new Date()
        data = data.getFullYear()
        var dataFim = data + 11
        var anos = []
        for (var index = 0; data < dataFim; data++, index++) {
            anos.push(data)   
        }
        $scope.AnosCard = anos
    }()

    $scope.$watch('customer.yearCard', function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue)
        $scope.mesesCard = []
        var anoAtual = (new Date()).getFullYear()
        console.log(newValue, anoAtual)
        if(newValue == anoAtual){
            var mesAtual = (new Date().getMonth()) + 1
            console.log(mesAtual)
            var meses = []
            for(mesAtual; mesAtual <= 12; mesAtual++){
                meses.push(mesAtual)
            }
            $scope.mesesCard = meses
        } else {
            $scope.mesesCard = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        }
    });
```